# How to perform batch inserts in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data of the following form in a textfile named myFile.txt:

```
id_1     POLYGON (1.137821,-129.141488|1.137874,-129.141493|1.137970,-129.141403|1.137994,-129.141349|1.138021,-129.141238)
id_2     LINESTRING (7.294799,-122.935414|7.294679,-122.935129)
id_3     POLYGON (1.139228,-129.143349|1.139228,-129.143401|1.139150,-129.143461|1.138930,-129.143451|1.138734,-129.143445|1.138630,-129.143390|1.138007,-129.142777|1.137906,-129.142629|1.137761,-129.142286|1.137796,-129.142214|1.137844,-129.142142|1.137839,-129.142067)
id_4     POINT (1.138007,-129.142777)
```

Here, `POLYGON`, `LINESTRING` and `POINT` specify the location of places in latitude and longitude. I want to batch insert this data into the following table:

```
create table idLatLongTable
(id character varying(250), geo_column geography);
```

My question is: How to do `batch insert` of this data in my table `idLatLongTable` ?.

I know how to do row-at-a-time insertions. However, I am unable to understand how to perform batch insertions on this table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is almost like [Well Known Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) but it isn't. Is this something that you have generated yourself? If so you should change your program to generate it in the WKT format. For example according to WKT your point field ought to look like

```
POINT (1.138007 -129.142777)
```

But it's

```
POINT (1.138007,-129.142777)
```

Similarly the correct representation for a linestring would be

```
LINESTRING (7.294799 -122.935414, 7.294679 -122.935129)
```

But in your data you have `,` where it should be space and `|` where it should be `,` so the first thing to do is to transform your data that's acceptable to PostGIS or any other spatially aware database.

While you are at it, please strip out the id_ part from the id. It's pointless to save `id_1` as a varchar, what should be saved is `1` in an integer field